# How can I prove that $Z_2\otimes Z_2$ is an invariant subgroup of $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I'm trying to prove that the subgroup $\{I , (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\} = Z_2 ⊗
Z_2$ is an invariant (normal) subgroup of $A_4$, where $(12)(34)$ and so on is a notation to indicate permutations (for example $(12)(34)$ would be the permutation $(2\quad 1\quad 4\quad 3)$), I used the equality sign to indicate that the two groups are isomorphic, and $A_4$ is the group of permutations of 4 objects.

The book says to "verify" this, and maybe the author means actually trying all 24 possible permutations ($p\in A_4$) and performing the operation $p^{-1}gp$ for $g\in Z_2 ⊗
Z_2$, but I was trying to come up with some argument in order not to do it manually and I couldn't think of anything.

Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: any conjugate of a permutation has the same shape as that permutation.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, this only proves the normality part, *provided that* the subgroup is contained in $A_4$.

Comment: @Devo 'twas only a hint ;-)

Comment: $\otimes$ is usually the symbol for the tensor product (which makes sense for abelian groups), not the direct product. For direct product, use $\times$;  for direct sum, use $\oplus$.